# What did Kim Jong-un travel to Beijing for?

Tags: china, north-korea

Many news outlets are claiming that Kim Jong-un traveled to Beijing today:

[CNN: 'Strong possibility' North Korea's Kim Jong Un made surprise Beijing visit](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/03/27/asia/china-north-korea-train-intl/index.html)

> Beijing (CNN) North Korea's leader Kim Jong Un is believed to have wrapped up an unprecedented whirlwind trip to the Chinese capital, ahead of a planned summit with his South Korean counterpart and a potential meeting with US President Donald Trump.

[CBC: Train believed to be carrying North Korean officials, and possibly Kim, leaves Beijing](http://www.cbc.ca/news/world/china-north-korea-kim-reports-1.4594724)

> A train believed to be carrying a senior North Korean delegation left the Chinese capital on Tuesday following a dramatic whirlwind visit that some reports said included the country's leader, Kim Jong-un.

[NYT: Bulletproof, Slow and Full of Wine: Kim Jong-un’s Mystery Train](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/03/27/world/asia/kim-jong-un-train-beijing.html)

> HONG KONG — A train, nearly as mysterious as its principal passenger, pulled into Beijing’s central train station Monday night, fueling speculation that Kim Jong-un, North Korea’s leader, had arrived in the capital for secret talks with his Chinese counterpart.

A few days later, speculations are confirmed:

[BBC: China and N Korea confirm Kim Jong-un visit](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-43564529)

> After days of speculation, it has been confirmed that North Korea's leader Kim Jong-un has visited China.

What was the purpose of the visit? Details seem few and far between at the moment.

Comment: Just as these articles indicate, its all speculation at this point. China being North Korea's most important ally, one could assume that this is to align their interests with regards to the purported upcoming meeting between Trump and Kim, but any full answer would be fully opinion-based

Comment: @WhokilledBiggieandTupac I don't think I have permission to.

Comment: @WhokilledBiggieandTupac Need view close votes privileged which is awarded at 250 reputation.

Comment: As it is, the question still isn’t good. 1) It’s the old question with an addendum at the end. You need to make it one coherent post. 2) “What did he travel for?” is still speculative. You could, however, ask what NK or China _say_ was the purpose of the trip.

Comment: Officially it's just about the cooperation of the two countries in a wide sense. However, it looks like China is worried about American military expansion on the Korean peninsula, so the national security was the primary topic. As such, one shouldn't expect too much information being revealed, until, at least, the forthcoming visit of Xi Jinping to the DPRK.

Comment: @chirlu I tried making it more coherent, let me know if it's better or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your BBC source hints at an answer:

> "The issue of denuclearisation of the Korean Peninsula can be resolved, if South Korea and the United States respond to our efforts with goodwill, create an atmosphere of peace and stability while taking progressive and synchronous measures for the realisation of peace," Mr Kim was reported saying.

So the unofficial visit discussed denuclearisation, what North Korea would gain from this and (presumably) whether China would support a proposal.